# Почему программа считает что роботов все еще 2? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код - https://onlinegdb.com/QPXDDvzry

```
class Robot:
    population = 0   

    def __init__(self , name):
        self.name = name
        print("Робот по имени - {0} инициализирован".format(self.name))
        Robot.population += 1   

    def say_Hi(self):
        return("Привет , меня зовут {0}".format(self.name))

    def delete(self):
        print("{0} был удален".format(self.name))
        return(Robot.population - 1)

    @staticmethod
    def how_Many():
        return(Robot.population)

Robotik1 = Robot("Droid1")
print(Robotik1.say_Hi())
Robotik2 = Robot("Droid2")
print(Robotik2.how_Many())

print(Robotik1.delete())
print(Robot.how_Many())
```

Comment: Вы в методе delete только возвращаете Robot.population - 1 но саму переменную при этом не меняете

Comment: Такие методы как `delete` обычно не должны ничего возвращать. Просто уменьшайте там переменную и ничего не возвращайте. И это должен быть метод класса по-хорошему тогда, если он меняет переменную класса и ему всё-равно от какого объекта он вызван.